# Closing Windows popups with python

Tags: python, windows, automation, pyautogui, pywinauto

At my current job, I'm developing an automation with Python and Pyautogui + Pywinauto in which I fill in forms built up by past programmers. Those forms pop up a Windows-type alert at the end with a close and an ok button, but I'm unable to reach those with either `pyautogui.click()` or `pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys(“%{F4}”)`.
As far as I know I cannot switch to selenium, because it is an offline windows application.

What should I do?

Comment: When you use PyWinAuto to iterate through the available controls, is the OK button among them?

Comment: for some reason this was not working with pyautogui, so i mixed them in my code

Comment: The available controls are the keyboard keys, but now you made me wonder if ‘enter’ will work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: By "Controls" I meant [Windows Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), such as in buttons, forms, layout panels, text boxes, etc.

Comment: did you tried `Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re="title of forms pop up a Windows")`?